# Is cudaMallocHost() , cudaCreateEvent() asynchronous with executing kernels?

Tags: cuda

I am running on a very strange issue with the Cuda Runtime API. Calls to functions like `cudaMallocHost()`, `cudaEventCreate()`, `cudaFree()` etc.. seem to be executed only when kernels finish execution on GPU. This kernels are all launched on a stream created with the `cudaStreamNonBlocking` flag. What is the problem? Do I have to put up some other flags somewhere?

Comment: cudaFree and cudaMalloc are synchronous.

Comment: This doesn't tell me much:( is there a way how to call a cudaMallocHost() etc that is executed while a kernel is running? I have some kernels that take seconds and they are hanging my process because of this issue

Answer (score 2):

They *could* be made asynchronous, but it wouldn't be surprising if they are not.

With respect to `cudaMallocHost()`, which requires that the host memory be mapped for the GPU: if the allocation can't be satisfied from a preallocated pool, the GPU's page tables must be edited.  It would not surprise me in the least if the driver had a restriction where it could not edit the page tables of an executing kernel. (Esp. since the page table editing must be done by kernel mode driver code.)

With respect to `cudaEventCreate()`, that really should be asynchronous since those allocations generally can be satisfied from a preallocated pool.  The main impediment there is that changing the behavior would break existing applications that rely on its current, synchronous behavior.

Freeing objects asynchronously requires the driver to track which objects are referenced in the command buffers submitted to the GPU, and defer the actual free operation until after the GPU has finished processing them. It is doable but I am not sure NVIDIA has done the work.

For `cudaFree()`, it is not possible to track references as you could for CUDA events (because pointers can be stored for running kernels to read and chase).  So for large vitrual address ranges that should be deallocated and unmapped, the free must be deferred until after *all* pending GPU operations have executed.  Again, doable but I am not sure NVIDIA has done the work.

I think NVIDIA generally expects developers to work around the lack of asynchrony in these entry points.

Comment: Uum this is not good at all...in my system I prepare the environment for one kernel and execute... Then I begin preparation for the next asynchronously... Due to this behaviour I am loosing performance since not everything goes asynchronous :( is there a way how to increase pools of pinned memory and events?

Comment: The only suggestion I can offer is to implement your own resource management. :-(